# Ansible: copy file depending on hostname or role

Tags: ansible

What's the best way to copy over a file depending on a hostname?

I need to copy over files with different content but with the same filename to several machines.

I have several files:

```
file.role1
file.role2
file.role3
```

Depending on hostname and/or role, I'd like like to copy `file.roleX` and rename it to `file`

Thanks.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Simplest:

```
- name: Copy file.role1 to host1
  copy: src=file.role1 dest=/somewhere/file
  when: inventory_hostname == "host1"
- name: Copy file.role2 to host2
  copy: src=file.role2 dest=/somewhere/file
  when: inventory_hostname == "host2"
```

Alternative, more compact:

```
- name: Copy file to host
  copy: src=file.{{ inventory_hostname }} dest=/somewhere/file
```

Or, using a template:

```
- name: Copy file to host
  template: src=file dest=/somewhere/file
```

where the template can be something like this:

```
{% if inventory_hostname == "host1" %}
{% include "file1" %}
{% endif %}
...
```

If you want different files in different roles, why don't you simply put this:

```
- name: Copy file.role1 to file
  copy: src=file.role1 dest=/somewhere/file
```

in each role's code?

There is no preferred way to do it - it depends on what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: bonus points for [TIMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)!

Comment: Thanks -- I was actually for a different apt.sources file depending on OS & architecture without creating a mess or having too many roles/a big inventory file. I went for a variable behind the hostname in the inventory file: sources_list=debian and that causes sources.list.debian to copy to sources.list.